# Aggregate items displaying only their number, and when zooming display each in QGIS

Tags: qgis

Is there a way in QGIS to configure such a display like in https://velobs.2p2r.org/? For example, aggregated POI at low zoom level and zooming separates POI.

Answer (score 10):

There is a styling option in `Layer Styling Panel` (<kbd>F7</kbd>) for this.

[image]

[image]

Useful links:

- [QGIS Documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#point-cluster-renderer)
- [Even more aggregations: QGIS point cluster renderer](https://anitagraser.com/2017/06/13/even-more-aggregations-qgis-point-cluster-renderer/)
- [QGIS Cluster Renderer Crowdfunding](https://north-road.com/qgis-cluster-renderer-crowdfunding/)